# Grid's Column Resizing leaves white space in the last column of kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Please help me to resolve the issue, Kendo's grid is leaving while space in the last column while resizing the columns.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While doing resizing the columns if you decrease it to minimum, there will be white space at right.

Following are some point that you can take care of

- Give the grid column width in percentage.
- You can set it to autofit, based on the data in the grid, the column width will be set automatically.
- you can handle resize event and set to autofit.

  ```
  var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
      grid.autoFitColumn(i);
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you